# Conditions for the existence of a probability with infinite support?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I'm trying to ad some probabilities on my model and I'm wondering which conditions are needed on my initial space.

I'm starting with a metric space X and consider the set of operators from X to itself equipped with the topology of compact convergence. Let's consider the Borel sigma algebra of this space. Does there always exists a Probability on this measurable space ?
Do I need some stronger assumptions on X ?

EDIT : I forgot to specify that I'm asking about the existence of a probability with a "large support", equal to the space or infinite

Thanks !

Comment: Not sure what you are asking.   Every (non-empty)  $\sigma$ algebra admits a probability distribution...just pick some point $s\in S$ and define $\mu(A)=1$ if $s\in A$ and $\mu (A)=0$ otherwise.  Granted, not a very interesting distribution.  Did you have more conditions in mind?

Comment: My bad, I forgot to ask for the support to be equal to the space itself or at least to be infinite

Comment: Ok, I suggest editing your post to reflect that.

Comment: [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/85837/can-we-put-a-probability-measure-on-every-sigma-algebra) seems relevant to the abstract problem.